# Implementing Navigation Drawer in android using different ways

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, navigation-drawer

[image]

I am working on an application, in which I need to implement navigation drawer. We have two different ways  of implement navigation drawer in android as shown in attached screen shots :

In first way the sliding list is over main content. In second type, sliding list becomes visible and make main content to slide left to right with Navigation Drawer list.

I goggled a lot about this and only got solution of first type. I want to implement Navigation drawer like second type in attached screenshot. So please tell me what changes I need to make.

Thanks.

Comment: You are only getting examples of the first type because that is the established [design pattern for a Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) for Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first case google's official Navigation Drawer is there.

And for the second case there's a third party library on github.
here's the link: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu
Also I feel you've to use ActionBarSherlock (again a third party library) in order to implement the second case.

Moreover the google's drawer method is the recommended one as it supports a stable action bar, from where you can choose items even when the drawer is open. Also the design + app flow is slick and faster in this case as compared to the third party lib.